# Count distinct dictionaries in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, count

I have a list of dictionaries: `[d1, d2, ...., d3]`. How can I efficiently (e.g. linear time) count distinct dictionaries in the list? Python can correctly compare dictionaries: `d1==d2`.  Dictionaries, lists and sets are unhashable.

Comment: what is the nature of your dictionaries? `str:in`, `str:str`? arbitrary_object:arbitrary_object?

Comment: They are counters: str:int

Comment: easy enough, then. see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you have a list of dictionaries which have items that are themselves hashable, then you can use a `frozenset` made out of the `.items()` inside another set:

```
>>> data = [{'a':1, 'b':2}, {'c':2, 'a':2}, {'b':2, 'a':1}, {'d':4}]
>>> {frozenset(d.items()) for d in data}
{frozenset({('c', 2), ('a', 2)}), frozenset({('a', 1), ('b', 2)}), frozenset({('d', 4)})}
```

And just take the length of that.

So in the above case,

```
>>> len({frozenset(d.items()) for d in data})
3
```

Comment: Nitpicking: The average time complexity of set comprehension is O(n) but it can be higher for the worst case.

Comment: How can I have a counter so that it gives the counts of each dictionary in the original list?

Comment: @guyguyguy12345 what?

Comment: e.g. d1 occurs 2 time, d2 occurs 5 times etc

Comment: ok, just do `collections.Counter(frozenset(d.items()) for d in data)` it's the same idea